# Issues with php_imagick.dll , i can't install it for PHP 8.1 with XAMPP

Tags: imagick

[image: MY PHP info]

i updated php.ini with : extension=imagick

and i'm receiving this error :

[image]

i checked php_imagick.dll to be for PHP 8.10 , X64 and Theard Safety to be sure i'm downloading the correct version .... from here : https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.7.0/windows

and the file is present on that specific path

the strange thing is that i'm download it for x64,,, and the error message tells me that is not compatible with win32 ... quite strange

i'm unable to fix this issue,,, and i'm out of ideas
can you help?
thanks in regards